# How to determine if gui is completely constructed in java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, progress-bar

I want to show a new JFrame when a button is clicked and also I'm calling another method and this method needs elements in that JFrame, but before completion of constructing gui my method is runnig. is there any way to determine when all elements of gui are constructed?

here is my code:

```
    public void run(String mergeLevel) {
    JProgressBar progressBar = addProgressBar();
    extractGrammar(progressBar);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to guarantee that the GUI is fully constructed before your method call, create a subclass of SwingWorker and put your method call in the `done()` method of SwingWorker after starting your GUI construction, which itself should be put on the swing thread via a Runnable and `SwingUtilities.invokeNow()`. The code will execute on the swing thread following the construction of your GUI.

Comment: SwingUtilities.invokeNow() ?= invokeLater/AndWait (both doRun.run())